# How to change option in categories in Opencart 1.5.6.1

Tags: php, opencart

I have only option of related products in Ctalog-->Products-->Links .I want to change Related Products to What's New. You can see just above the footer. 
http://sophieandtrey.com/whatsnew/floral-print-pants-navy

I want my page like:
http://www.tobi.com/product/54959-tobi-keira-dress?color_id=76009

Please guide me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, There is default Module to show latest product

```
catalog/module/latest
```

you can configure it to show on content bottom.

It doesn't make sense changing related product to latest product, if you want so
Then go to

```
theme/template/product/product.tpl
```

remove

```
<a href="#tab-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>
```

In `product.tpl` you can see related products by `print_r($products)` you can use it where you wanted according to requirement.

Hope This helps.